# Expect tcl "file exists" function failing even though "ls" shows file

Tags: tcl, expect

I spawn a shell instance with `spawn sh` and I run some commands to generate files. I then use `verify_file_exists` below to check that they were created. Using `file exists` always fails though! I have edited the procedure below to further illustrate my problem. I explicitly create `hello.txt` and check for it's existence, but it always fails.

```
proc verify_file_exists {filename} {
    send "touch hello.txt\r"
    if {[file exists hello.txt]} {
        puts "hello.txt found\r"
    } else {
        puts "Failed to find hello.txt\r" # Always fails
        exit 1
    }
}
```

I tried something else too: I put an `interact ++ return` statement right before my call to `verify_file_exists` and that puts me in the `sh` instance. I then run `touch hi.txt`, then run `expect` and enter an `expect` instance. Then if I run `file exists hi.txt` I *do* get a positive response of `1`! So this can't be a permission issue, right?

If I do the same thing as above but manually `touch hello.txt`, the procedure still fails at the `file exists` line.

Why is `file exists` not working as `expect`ed?

NOTE: Putting quotes around `hello.txt` does not solve the issue.

Comment: What happens if you provide a file name with an absolute path?

Comment: @PeterLewerin I tried using an absolute path and it did not work. I *did* try an absolute path to a file that exists beforehand, and it did work. This makes me think it really has something to do with the fact that the file is created during the script.

Comment: I suppose that the query that `file exists` makes could be processed before the `touch` is complete.

Comment: @PeterLewerin After the `touch` command I tried putting `interact ++ return` and then ran `ls` to verify that the file was indeed created. Then I typed ++ to return control, and I still see the same failure.

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot that. I'm going to stop making noise now: there are others here who, unlike me, know their way around expect.

Comment: Is the spawned shell's PWD different from the expect process's PWD? If you do have sent a `cd` they will be different. Or if the spawed shell is a login shell, it will be in your homedir, while your expect process sits in whereever you were when you launched it. Try `puts "expect: [pwd]"` and `send "echo shell:; pwd\r"; expect $the_prompt` to check

Comment: A quick expect technique to touch a file: `close [open $filename a]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `send`, you need to wait for the next shell prompt to show up which means the last command has completed. That's why `send` is usually followed by `expect`. For a quick test you can also add a `sleep 1` after `send`.

Another possibility is that the Expect process' current dir is not the same as the *spawn*ed shell process' current dir.

A simple example for both:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat example.exp
proc expect_prompt {} {
    expect -re {bash-[.0-9]+[#$] $}
}

spawn bash --norc
expect_prompt

send "rm -f foo bar && touch foo\r"
expect_prompt
if { [file exists foo] } {
    send "# found foo!\r"
    expect_prompt
}

send "mkdir -p tmp && cd tmp && rm -f bar && touch bar\r"
expect_prompt
if { ! [file exists bar] } {
    send "# where's bar?\r"
    expect_prompt
}

send "exit\r"
expect eof
[STEP 102] $ expect example.exp
spawn bash --norc
bash-4.4$ rm -f foo && touch foo
bash-4.4$ # found foo!
bash-4.4$ mkdir -p tmp && cd tmp && rm -f bar && touch bar
bash-4.4$ # where's bar?
bash-4.4$ exit
exit
[STEP 103] $
```

Comment: The answer is that expect's current dir and the spawned shell's current dir are indeed not the same. I am working around this by passing the `pwd` around as a variable. Thank you!